# Why Observers added as observeForever to LiveData must be removed?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I've read on [Android LiveData documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) that:

> You can register an observer without an associated LifecycleOwner object using the observeForever(Observer) method. In this case, the observer is considered to be always active and is therefore always notified about modifications. You can remove these observers calling the removeObserver(Observer) method.

I'm building an app using MVVM architecture pattern using [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and declaring LiveDatas inside my ViewModel class. At my viewModel I have set a `observeForever` to a LiveData:

```
val password by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<String>()
}

init {
    initObservable()
}

private fun initObservable() {
    password.observeForever {
        ...
    }
}
```

From what I understood from the documentation, I should remove the observer everytime the view that instantiates the ViewModel (with the previous code) was destroyed, right? But shouldn't the Observers be destroyed once the view is destroyed (since the ViewModel instance was instantiated in the view and will also be destroyed)?

Comment: How are you obtaining this `ViewModel` instance? Why `password` is being observed from within `ViewModel` itself?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*"I should remove the observer everytime the view that instantiates the ViewModel (with the previous code) was destroyed, right?"*

If you are obsering a `LiveData` in **ViewModel** using `observeForever(observer)`:

- You should not worry about View's lifecycle, because it is different from ViewModel's life. ViewModel should be able to out-live the View that creates it. Instead, the framework will call `onCleared()` when the ViewModel is not needed, so that's where you should handle removing the observer.

If you are observing a `LiveData` in **View** using `observe(lifecyclerowner, observer)`

- Observers will automatically removed by the framework when the lifecycleowner is destroyed.

*"But shouldn't the Observers be destroyed once the view is destroyed (since the ViewModel instance was instantiated in the view and will also be destroyed)?"*

This question is more of a Java question than Android.

Think about what it means by "being destroyed". When a View or ViewModel is destroyed by the Android Framework, it does not mean that the object is completely removed from the memory. Your activities and fragments will not be garbage collected as long as there are other objects (such as **observer**) that has reference to them.

If you call `observe(activity, observer)`, then the Android Framework can track the connection between the `activity` instance and the `observer` instance, and therefore it can kill `observer` when it wants to kill `activity`. However if you simply call `observeForever(observer)` there is simply no way for Android Framework to tell which object this observer belongs to.

Answer (score 4):

Implementing Sanlok Lee's answer in a **ViewModel**, it would look like this:

```
val password by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<String>()
}

private val passwordObserver = Observer<String> {
    ...
}

init {
    initObservable()
}

private fun initObservable() {
    password.observeForever(passwordObserver)
}

override fun onCleared() {
    password.removeObserver(passwordObserver)
    super.onCleared()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> From what I understood from the documentation, I should remove the
>   observer everytime the view that instantiates the ViewModel

To achieve this you should instantiate your viewmodel inside the View (Activity, Fragment) and observe the livedata like this

```
val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        model.getUsers().observe(this, Observer<List<User>>{ users ->
            // update UI
        })
```

by passing `this` you tie observing livedata to `view's` lifecycle, so when View (Activity, Fragment) will be destroyed both viewmodel and observer will be destroyed.